# How to edit event which was saved ealier from full calender in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Full Calender in my application and want to edit the events which was saved earlier.
How can I edit the events? My code is as shown below.
I am using SQL as a database. Just want to edit the event which are displyed in the full calender.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "schedule";
}

@Html.Partial("_Calendar")


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: { left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title' },
            selectable: true,
            theme: true,
            minTime: '8:00',
            defaultEventMinutes: 30,
            maxTime: '17:00',
            allDaySlot: false,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            weekends: false,
            firstHour: 9,
            selectHelper: true,

            select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                //var date1 = dateFormat(new Date(start).toGMTString(), 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss');
                //var date2 = dateFormat(new Date(end).toGMTString(), 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss');


                var title = prompt('Event Title:');

                    if (!!title) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { Start: start.toJSON(), End: end.toJSON(), Note: title },
                            url: rootURL + "Contractor/schedule/SaveSchedule",
                            color:'yellow',
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#eventToAdd').modal('hide');
                                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', { title: title, start: start, end: end, allDay: allDay }, true);                                        
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                $("#eventToAdd").dialog("close");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

            },
            eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, calEvent, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                var date1 = dateFormat(new Date(event.start), 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss');
                var date2 = dateFormat(new Date(event.end), 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'id':event.id, 'Start': date1, 'End': date2},
                    url: "/Contractor/schedule/UpdateSchedule",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {


                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
            },
            editable: true,
            events: '@Url.Action("Getevent","Schedule")',
            eventColor: '#028323'

        });


    });

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could implement following method:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {}
```

This function is written in the same way as eventDrop.

The parameter element is the div that forms the event, you can add an onclick event to this or append some html to its contents with a button. That way you can show your popup or navigate to an edit page. You can use something like firebug to inspect and adjust the html and see what is possible.

For more detailed information, you can check http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

There you can add an onclick handler or maybe an image with an onclick handler. In the onclick you can show a popup of some sort or navigate to an other page. In the popup or the other page you can make a form to edit your event. When the edit is complete reload the events or navigate back to your calendar and you will see the updated event.

Comment: Would you please give me a Descriptive Answer Because I got confused now. That where will be this function written ?

Comment: I added some usefull information in my answer for you. Maybe you already have, but be sure to check the official documentation from full calendar; it is very usefull.